# How to migrate the Project Web App 2010 site collection and BI center from farm A to farm B

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, migration, project-server, business-intelligence

We have 2 farms, both have Project server service application installed. I want to migrate all the project data as well as the BI center (with reports) from one farm to another.

I have moved the 4 databases (Draft, Published, Archive, Reporting) to destination farm using backup/restore method. Then I goto Sharepoint CA -> manage service application -> Project server service application -> create a new Project web app site (http://sharepoint/pwa/), in the database fields I filled in the 4 databases I moved over. (according to [msdn article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961887(v=office.14).aspx)) After then, all projects are  working as expected.

However we have some list, library under BI center site. The URL is like http://sharepoint/pwa/ProjectBICenter/. So I run backup-spsite and restore-spsite for "http://sharepoint/pwa/". I found all items under /ProjectBICenter/ are recovered. But my project web app ( "http://sharepoint/pwa/" ) is now throwing error everywhere!

Sharepoint ULS log said:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process
>   the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the
>   error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information
>   back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
>   Server stack trace:
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Interfaces.IAuthentication.GetUserByName(String
>   username) 
>       at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.AuthenticationHelper.AuthenticateUserByName(String
>   userName, Guid siteId)

I can delete the office web app and do it all over again. But what should be the correct procedure?  (The source farm's /PWA/ is stored in a very hugh content database. This DB contains several site collection but I only want to copy /PWA/ not entire database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortheuntally , the above mentioned MSDN link describes only 
 how to move the Microsoft Project Server 2010 databases to a new instance of SQL Server **while keeping the same PWA site**. it's not describe how to migrate project server to another server / farm.

So it's normal behavior to don't find `http://sharepoint/pwa/ProjectBICenter/`

Because the `ProjectBICenter` site is stored in a content database that you didn't move it during the migration process.

So, You should be aware of migrating Project Server 2010 will require migrating five databases not only four,

- Web Application Content Database
- Draft,
- Published,
- Archive,
- Reporting

Another thing you do it is running [backup-spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx) rather than
using **database-attach upgrade method** to move this content database. a [backup-spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx) will Performs a backup of a site collection. but with project server, it's not working as expected.

I also noticed at the end of your question , you don't need to migrate the content database because it has a huge size ,

So in this case , because of `ProjectBICenter` is a **subsite** from `PWA site collection`, so you can migrate it by using [Export-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.14).aspx) from the old site collection then [Import-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613(v=office.14).aspx) it to the new site collection.

**For Example, **

```
export-spweb "http://sharepoint/pwa/ProjectBICenter" -path "D:\Temp\migration\backupfile.cmp"
```

Import subsite to new site collection using this command:

```
Import-SPWeb "http://sharepoint/pwa/ProjectBICenter" -path "D:\Temp\migration\backupfile.cmp"  –UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

Comment: Thank you for reading my long question and your solution it perfect!

Comment: you are welcome my bro :) , thanks for your appreciation

Comment: Sorry for asking in old thread. I just found that the destination PWA cannot create new project. Also all the old project's subsites are not migrated. I am afraid I have to migrate entire "http://sharepoint/pwa". Do you think I can simply use backup-spsite / restore-spsite to do so?

Comment: NP, you could ask at any time and at any place :). regarding your question are you restore the content database and and mount it to your web application ?

Comment: I have tried backup/restore-spsite but it will not work. So I change to content DB mounting method and seems good now. (I have many site collection in the same content DB that's why I try to avoid) Thanks.